# Asp.Net Identity - Migration update results in error "There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database."

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I have a fresh SQL Server database, hosted in Microsoft Azure.

Whenever I run the following commands in the Visual Studio for Mac terminal window:

```
dotnet ef migrations add "CreateProdAuthDatabase_PROD"
dotnet ef database update
```

I get the following error:

[image]

Why is this happening? I delete the ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot file BEFORE I run the migration, and a fresh version of this file is generated, right at the point of me running the migration terminal command.

UPDATE
Here is the generated snapshot file:

```
// <auto-generated />
```

using System;
using FIRECalculator.Migrations;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion;

#nullable disable

namespace FIRECalculator.Migrations
{
[DbContext(typeof(ApplicationDbContext))]
partial class ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot : ModelSnapshot
{
protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
modelBuilder
.HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "8.0.1")
.HasAnnotation("Relational:MaxIdentifierLength", 128);

```
        SqlServerModelBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumns(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity("FIRECalculator.Auth.Entities.ApplicationUser", b =>
            {
                b.Property<string>("Id")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(450)");

                b.Property<int>("AccessFailedCount")
                    .HasColumnType("int");

                b.Property<DateTime?>("AccountUnlockedDateTimeUtc")
                    .HasColumnType("datetime2");

                b.Property<DateTime?>("BirthdayDateTime")
                    .HasColumnType("datetime2");

                b.Property<int?>("BirthdayDay")
                    .HasColumnType("int");

                b.Property<int?>("BirthdayMonth")
                    .HasColumnType("int");

                b.Property<int?>("BirthdayYear")
                    .HasColumnType("int");

                b.Property<string>("City")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.Property<string>("ConcurrencyStamp")
                    .IsConcurrencyToken()
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.Property<string>("Email")
                    .HasMaxLength(256)
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(256)");

                b.Property<bool>("EmailConfirmed")
                    .HasColumnType("bit");

                b.Property<DateTime?>("EmailConfirmedDateTimeUtc")
                    .HasColumnType("datetime2");

                b.Property<string>("FirstName")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.Property<bool?>("IsBanned")
                    .HasColumnType("bit");

                b.Property<bool?>("IsSubscribedToNewsletter")
                    .HasColumnType("bit");

                b.Property<string>("LastName")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.Property<bool>("LockoutEnabled")
                    .HasColumnType("bit");

                b.Property<DateTimeOffset?>("LockoutEnd")
                    .HasColumnType("datetimeoffset");

                b.Property<string>("NormalizedEmail")
                    .HasMaxLength(256)
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(256)");

                b.Property<string>("NormalizedUserName")
                    .HasMaxLength(256)
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(256)");

                b.Property<bool?>("OverrideAndIgnoreSubscriptionTier")
                    .HasColumnType("bit");

                b.Property<DateTime?>("OverrideAndIgnoreSubscriptionTierEndDateTimeUtc")
                    .HasColumnType("datetime2");

                b.Property<DateTime?>("OverrideAndIgnoreSubscriptionTierStartDateTimeUtc")
                    .HasColumnType("datetime2");

                b.Property<string>("PasswordHash")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.Property<string>("PhoneNumber")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.Property<bool>("PhoneNumberConfirmed")
                    .HasColumnType("bit");

                b.Property<byte[]>("ProfilePicture")
                    .HasColumnType("varbinary(max)");

                b.Property<string>("SecurityStamp")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.Property<DateTime?>("SubscriptionTierExpiresDateTimeUtc")
                    .HasColumnType("datetime2");

                b.Property<string>("SubscriptionTierFrequency")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.Property<DateTime?>("SubscriptionTierPaymentDateTimeUtc")
                    .HasColumnType("datetime2");

                b.Property<DateTime?>("SubscriptionTierStartDateTimeUtc")
                    .HasColumnType("datetime2");

                b.Property<string>("SubscriptionTierType")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.Property<bool>("TwoFactorEnabled")
                    .HasColumnType("bit");

                b.Property<bool?>("UserAccountIsLockedOut")
                    .HasColumnType("bit");

                b.Property<string>("UserName")
                    .HasMaxLength(256)
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(256)");

                b.HasKey("Id");

                b.HasIndex("NormalizedEmail")
                    .HasDatabaseName("EmailIndex");

                b.HasIndex("NormalizedUserName")
                    .IsUnique()
                    .HasDatabaseName("UserNameIndex")
                    .HasFilter("[NormalizedUserName] IS NOT NULL");

                b.ToTable("AspNetUsers", (string)null);
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole", b =>
            {
                b.Property<string>("Id")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(450)");

                b.Property<string>("ConcurrencyStamp")
                    .IsConcurrencyToken()
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.Property<string>("Name")
                    .HasMaxLength(256)
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(256)");

                b.Property<string>("NormalizedName")
                    .HasMaxLength(256)
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(256)");

                b.HasKey("Id");

                b.HasIndex("NormalizedName")
                    .IsUnique()
                    .HasDatabaseName("RoleNameIndex")
                    .HasFilter("[NormalizedName] IS NOT NULL");

                b.ToTable("AspNetRoles", (string)null);
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRoleClaim<string>", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("Id")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasColumnType("int");

                SqlServerPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumn(b.Property<int>("Id"));

                b.Property<string>("ClaimType")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.Property<string>("ClaimValue")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.Property<string>("RoleId")
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(450)");

                b.HasKey("Id");

                b.HasIndex("RoleId");

                b.ToTable("AspNetRoleClaims", (string)null);
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim<string>", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("Id")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasColumnType("int");

                SqlServerPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumn(b.Property<int>("Id"));

                b.Property<string>("ClaimType")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.Property<string>("ClaimValue")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.Property<string>("UserId")
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(450)");

                b.HasKey("Id");

                b.HasIndex("UserId");

                b.ToTable("AspNetUserClaims", (string)null);
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin<string>", b =>
            {
                b.Property<string>("LoginProvider")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(450)");

                b.Property<string>("ProviderKey")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(450)");

                b.Property<string>("ProviderDisplayName")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.Property<string>("UserId")
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(450)");

                b.HasKey("LoginProvider", "ProviderKey");

                b.HasIndex("UserId");

                b.ToTable("AspNetUserLogins", (string)null);
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole<string>", b =>
            {
                b.Property<string>("UserId")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(450)");

                b.Property<string>("RoleId")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(450)");

                b.HasKey("UserId", "RoleId");

                b.HasIndex("RoleId");

                b.ToTable("AspNetUserRoles", (string)null);
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken<string>", b =>
            {
                b.Property<string>("UserId")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(450)");

                b.Property<string>("LoginProvider")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(450)");

                b.Property<string>("Name")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(450)");

                b.Property<string>("Value")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.HasKey("UserId", "LoginProvider", "Name");

                b.ToTable("AspNetUserTokens", (string)null);
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRoleClaim<string>", b =>
            {
                b.HasOne("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole", null)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("RoleId")
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                    .IsRequired();
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim<string>", b =>
            {
                b.HasOne("FIRECalculator.Auth.Entities.ApplicationUser", null)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("UserId")
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                    .IsRequired();
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin<string>", b =>
            {
                b.HasOne("FIRECalculator.Auth.Entities.ApplicationUser", null)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("UserId")
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                    .IsRequired();
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole<string>", b =>
            {
                b.HasOne("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole", null)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("RoleId")
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                    .IsRequired();

                b.HasOne("FIRECalculator.Auth.Entities.ApplicationUser", null)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("UserId")
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                    .IsRequired();
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken<string>", b =>
            {
                b.HasOne("FIRECalculator.Auth.Entities.ApplicationUser", null)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("UserId")
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                    .IsRequired();
            });
```

#pragma warning restore 612, 618
}
}
}

...and here is the ApplicationUser, which inherits from IdentityUser:

```
public sealed class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
```

{
public string? FirstName { get; set; }

```
public string? LastName { get; set; }

public string? City { get; set; }

public byte[]? ProfilePicture { get; set; }

public DateTime? EmailConfirmedDateTimeUtc { get; set; }

public bool? UserAccountIsLockedOut { get; set; }

public DateTime? AccountUnlockedDateTimeUtc { get; set; }

public bool? IsBanned { get; set; }
public int? BirthdayDay { get; set; }
public int? BirthdayMonth { get; set; }
public int? BirthdayYear { get; set; }
public DateTime? BirthdayDateTime { get; set; }
public bool? IsSubscribedToNewsletter { get; set; }
public string? SubscriptionTierType { get; set; } //(FREE, Pro, Premium)
public DateTime? SubscriptionTierStartDateTimeUtc { get; set; }
public DateTime? SubscriptionTierExpiresDateTimeUtc { get; set; }
public DateTime? SubscriptionTierPaymentDateTimeUtc { get; set; }
public string? SubscriptionTierFrequency { get; set; } //(Monthly/Annual)
public bool? OverrideAndIgnoreSubscriptionTier { get; set; }
public DateTime? OverrideAndIgnoreSubscriptionTierStartDateTimeUtc { get; set; }
public DateTime? OverrideAndIgnoreSubscriptionTierEndDateTimeUtc { get; set; }
```

}

UPDATE 2:

Here is the ApplicationDbContext file:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

{
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
    // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
    // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
}
```

}

UPDATE 3:

Here is some key code in my Program.cs file:

```
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>()
.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
.AddSignInManager()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Are you trying to create the AspNetRoles manually? This table is handled by Identity.

Comment: No, I'm simply creating an ApplicationUser that inherits from IdentityUser, and then running the migration commands (which generate the snapshot file and the identityschema files). But when I try and update the database, I get this error...? (I've added an update containing the snapshot file and the ApplicationUser file)

Comment: What does your DB context inherit from? Can you show me that part?

Comment: I've added the ApplicationDbContext file code to my post. Thanks!

Comment: I've also added some key code from my Program.cs file

Comment: I've fixed it by deleting the "designer.cs" of the identity schema, then running the migration again.

Comment: Ah glad you got it!

Comment: Based on your error as the database entity alreday exists there, so migration causing that error, so either removing the entity or designer with cs file should resolve your issue which seems you have already accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by deleting the IdentitySchema.Designer.cs file, before running the migration again.